# Problem accessing a MySQL database over ODBC

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, database, odbc

```
OdbcDataReader q = dbc.Query("SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `id`=" + id.ToString());
if (q.RecordsAffected < 1)
{
    this.Exists = false;
}
else
{
    this.Exists = true;
    this.Author = q.GetString(6);
}
```

The server returns `No data exists for the row/column.`

My database table is structured like this (screencap from phpMyAdmin)
http://1.img.anyhub.net/1243660397_6485910f8b3fc9ee3e2d93831ad554fd.png

By the way, `dbc` is just a database connection class of mine; the `Query()` function is this:

```
public OdbcDataReader Query(string QueryStr)
{
    OdbcCommand q = new OdbcCommand(QueryStr, conn);
    OdbcDataReader r = q.ExecuteReader();
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use DataReader.Read method before you can get data from it.

```
q.Read(); 
this.Author = q.GetString(6);
```

And I recommend using a using block with you DataReader and Command objects

Comment: Jesus... How the hell did I manage to miss the Read()?  
I also have that all in blocks, but I just copy/pasted the relevant bits.

Comment: I feel pretty embarrassed now.